# How to paste previously prepared code snippets in Vim?

Tags: vim, paste

In Windows, using the AutoHotkey utility, it's possible to write simple scripts to expand some text in an editor of choice (e.g. Visual Studio's editor).

For example, if in Visual Studio editor I type:

> ```
> d1 [TAB]
> ```

(i.e. press the keys in sequence: <kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>) the above *"d1"* text can be replaced with one or more lines of code snippets. The mapping between *"d1"* and the expanded lines of code is specified in a AutoHotkey script.

This is very convenient e.g. for demos; for example: at some point if I'd like to enter a whole function body, assuming that I associated it to e.g. *"d3"*, I can simply press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> on the keyboard, and I get the function body automatically pasted in the editor in current cursor location; and I can have different code snippets associated to different key combinations, e.g.

```
d1 --> DoSomething() function definition
d2 --> class Foo definition
d3 --> test code xyz...
```

Is it possible to achieve the same goal using Vim?

In other words, I'd like to have a set of code snippets previously prepared, and I'd like to paste each one of them in my currently edited source code file in Vim, in a way similar to what I described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic expansion can be done via the built-in *abbreviations*, for example:

```
:inoreabb d1 DoSomething()<CR>{<CR><CR>}<CR><Up><Up>
```

Read more at `:help abbreviations`.

---

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used snipMate that does something like what you're describing.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php%3Fscript_id%3D2540

Comment: Thanks. I've watched the associated screencast and it seems to be what I'm looking for.